# How to add help text next to CommandButton in Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocktable

How can I have textHelp next to the `Find` button as shown below.
[image]

here is my Visualforce page source:

```
<table style="width: {!aWidth}">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 50px;"><span class="labelCol">Search:</span></td>
          <td style="width: 50%"><apex:inputText style="width:100%" value="{!SearchText}" /></td>
          <td>
            <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;</span>
            <apex:actionStatus id="SearchIcon">
              <apex:facet name="start">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                  <apex:commandButton style="float: left;" disabled="true" value="Find" />
                  <img style="float: left;" src="/img/loading24.gif" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:facet>
              <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!Find}" value="Find" rerender="BoxPanel" status="SearchIcon" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: my question is totally different....please have a look and compare the two

Comment: Have you tried applying the solution used in there? You should be able to get the help text using the same technique and just insert it into your markup where you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `title` attribute of a span tag to show the help text on hover. Use an help icon to improve the UX. I have added this line to your code `<span title="This is a really really long help text"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1156/fugue/16/question_frame.png" /></span>`. See the screenshot below.

Screen[image]

**Updated code**

```
<table style="width: {!aWidth}">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 50px;"><span class="labelCol">Search:</span></td>
          <td style="width: 50%"><apex:inputText style="width:100%" value="{!SearchText}" /></td>
          <td>
            <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;</span>
            <apex:actionStatus id="SearchIcon">
              <apex:facet name="start">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                  <apex:commandButton style="float: left;" disabled="true" value="Find" />
                  <img style="float: left;" src="/img/loading24.gif" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:facet>
              <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!Find}" value="Find" rerender="BoxPanel" status="SearchIcon" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        <span title="This is a really really long help text"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1156/fugue/16/question_frame.png" /></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Div tag and enclose both the command button and the help text in the div tag. Or If you want display tooltip, set value to the title property in the command button,